# Sending ctrl + z to console program

Tags: c, input, console, terminal

I have a simple console program written in C and want to abort a text input with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. How is it possible?

**Edit:** Here is some code (untested).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float var;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &var); // enter a float or press CTRL+Z

        if( ??? ) // if CTRL+Z was pressed
        {
            break;
        }

        // do something with var
    }

    printf("Job done!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like the process should stop reading input and go in background at the same time?

Comment: More precisely I have a loop that waits for user input each iteration and I want to break this loop (thus the input) with CTRL + Z.

Comment: Okay, here. But I can't test it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically like this:

```
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    /* process valid input */
} else {
    /* Ctrl+Z pressed */
}
```

There may be complications if you press Ctrl+Z in the middle of the line, but start with the basic.

---

Edit after OP was updated

You have

```
scanf("%lf", &var);
```

`scanf` returns the number of assignments it did. In your case, you only have 1 variable, so `scanf` returns 1 in the normal case or 0 when it fails. Just check the return value

```
int n = scanf("%lf", &var);
/* test the return value of scanf: 1 all ok; 0 no conversions; EOF: error/failure */
if (n != 1)
{
    break;
}
```

PS: Oh ... the specifier "%lf" in scanf requires a `double`, `var` in your program is a `float`. Correct that too

Comment: scanf would return EOF too, if it reaches the end of file, so check for that too. a return value of 0 might just mean the user entered somehing not a float in this case

Comment: @nos: In this case I have to press Enter after pressing Ctrl+Z, so I could define a letter (e.g. `q`) to break the loop but I'm searching for something better. B.t.w.: this is not for a real program, but for self-study.

Comment: @Sven: the safest way to get user's input is to `fgets` then `sscanf`.

Comment: To get Ctrl-Z as input on a terminal, that terminal has to have ISIG disabled. Raw mode has ISIG disabled. See the manpage for termios(3).

Comment: Okay, I handled it with the scanf return value, becaus I have to code on a Windows machine :-( . Otherwise I would try the POSIX signals.

Comment: Doing it with return value has one big advantage: if (when!) you upgrade your program to accept redirections (rather than direct console input) it is already working.

Answer (score 1):

use *signal.h* to help trap the `SIGTSTP` sent when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. Note that you'll want to catch SIGTSTP and not SIGSTOP as pausing is a *required* action for SIGSTOP by only the *default* action for SIGTSTP.

You may also run into problems not having `scanf()` return when the signal is generated. Luckily for you, that question has been asked and answered quite nicely already :) [Scanf with Signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512853/scanf-with-signals)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UNIX-like operating system, ctrl-z sends a SIGSTOP, which you can generate programmatically, and catch with sigaction.